# How do I avoid storing user passwords I need to access in plaintext?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a client for an API that doesn't fit the profile for normal clients for this API. This api requires users to be authenticated with a user/password pair or a session key. The session key, however, only lasts as long as the user isn't authenticated elsewhere. It's not feasible to have the user retype the password everytime the session expires. For the moment, while developing the application, I've been storing the passwords in plaintext in MySQL. I would like to avoid this for the production client. How do I secure these passwords when I need them in plaintext to send them to the service?

Comment: Store their hashed form then compare that hash with the database-stored hash?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Block ciphers, salt, AES, MySQL, and best practices around credential storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734892/block-ciphers-salt-aes-mysql-and-best-practices-around-credential-storage)

Comment: Read the comments on that question I linked to.  SLaks suggestion of RSA is much better, and is what I ended up doing in a similar situation.

Comment: If my database and web server are the same server, are there still advantages to asymmetric encryption?

Comment: Dupes of http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bphp%5d%20password

Answer (score 0):

Use database encryption to send and receive sensitive information.

That way, the hacker would also need to have access to the database and figure out the encryption pattern in order to reveal the password. There are software that does it for you such as ProtectDB (http://www.safenet-inc.com/data-protection/database-encryption/protect-db/)

or you can make your own!

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt the password on signup with an hashing algorithm such as SHA512 (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php).

Then, when the user logs in with their username and password, encrypt the password, and check it against the stored one in the database.

Comment: This solution does not work in this case (although that's normally what I do when I'm in charge of authentication), because I need to send the plaintext password to a third party to gain access to their part of the system. They do the hash comparison.

Comment: AH, so you aren't in control of the API? And they require you to send the username in plaintext? The only other way I would look at doing it, is making sure the connection is encrypted (SSL) and sending it plaintext through that tunnel

Comment: Yeah, the connection to the API is HTTPS, but I have to store the users' passwords so I can send them to the service at any time. I didn't want to just put them in plaintext.

Comment: Sorry, understand now, couldn't you encrypt the data with a private key and store it, then unencrypt it when required to send?